# webpack-dev-server cli --open localhost on different port

Tags: webpack

When running webpack-dev-server, I am running [Jarvis](https://github.com/zouhir/jarvis) on port 1337 for auditing purposes, while my app is running locally on port 8080. I would like to open localhost:1337 in my browser automatically via webpack. When I run webpack-dev-server --open it opens localhost:8080 (which is expected) Is it possible to open localhost on a different port (1337 in this case) ?
I have come across the --open-page flag but do not see any other options.

Comment: or do you want to just automatically open the browser pointing at `http://localhost:1337` and keep webpack running on port 8080? if so, what is your operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux**:

```
webpack-dev-server & xdg-open http://localhost:1337
```

The single ampersand is important. With this command you can omit `--open` and `--port` (which will then default to `8080`.

Comment: this worked for me, thank you. I'm using a mac so I switched the `xdg-open` command to just be `open` and everything worked as expected.